# How to make a number counter stay at current number for anyone visiting site

Tags: javascript, html

I added a number counter to a website I made.  I need to make it so the number count stays at the current number.  For example, if the number is at 3 and I click add one then the next person who visits the website should see 4.  Right now it resets to zero every time someone different visits the website.

Html

```
 <div class="box">    
      <input id="qty" value="0" />
        <button id="up" onclick="modify_qty(1)">+ one</button>
    <div class="mastfoot">
```

Javascript

```
function modify_qty(val) {
    var qty = document.getElementById('qty').value;
    var new_qty = parseInt(qty,10) + val;

    if (new_qty < 0) {
        new_qty = 0;
    }

    document.getElementById('qty').value = new_qty;
    return new_qty;
}
```

Comment: JavaScript is client side;  if you are trying to keep track of the number of people that visited your site and send that number to others, it has to be sent back to the server in some form.

Comment: You would need a database or a server-side file or something similar to keep track of that.

Comment: can you access the servers file system? Are you using php?

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is use persistent data storage. The variables are created each time the page is created. So each time the variables are overwritten by 0 as they are recreated.

You can use a server side language like PHP to store data in the database or you use write to a file, then retrieve the data using AJAX requests to make it dynamic.

Comment: Thanks... I will try PHP and see if I can get that to work!